# Angular 11 : Dynamically adding URL into Iframe but it is giving error

Tags: angular, iframe, dynamic-url

I'm getting some URLs dynamically and i tried to add that urls into Iframes but it is giving an error saying: **unsafe value used in a resource URL context**

> Here is my code of angular component :

```
 url = "http://xyz.abc.in/0b82d";
 public resumeurl : any;
  jobform: jobformfinal = <jobformfinal>{};
  public retailerObject: any = {}
  
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private callapi: ServiceService, private _router: Router,private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  ngOnInit(): void {

        this.callapi.resume(this.mobile).subscribe(res => {
          if (res.data.resume_short_url !== "" || res.data.resume_short_url !== null) {
            this.resumeurl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
          }
        })
      }
    },
    err => {
      if (err.status == 422) {
        alert(err.error.errors.error_description)
      }
    })
  }
```

In HTML component i have simply written an iframe tag :

```
<iframe src="{{resumeurl}}" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
                    title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

> but still it is an giving below error :

ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)
at ɵɵsanitizeResourceUrl (core.js:6043)
at elementPropertyInternal (core.js:10025)